# Issue with FOR loop applied with SUBSTR & INSTR operations

Tags: sql, oracle, loops, plsql

I've written a small program to find the position of last space in a string. If  found, take all the characters before that space and keep on doind this operation until the result is of length less than or equal to 20.
But it seems the program is not working as expected.

Here is the program.

```
declare
    v_building_nam varchar2(100) :='lnkilap Mahallesi Üntel Sok. B1Blok';
begin
    FOR i in 1..10
    LOOP
        EXIT when length(v_building_nam) <=20;

        v_building_nam := substr(v_building_nam,1,instr(v_building_nam,' ',-1));

    END LOOP;

    dbms_output.put_line(v_building_nam);  

END;
```

Output :

```
lnkilap Mahallesi Üntel Sok.
```

It seems the operation just working for the first time and the loop then runs upto 10 times without the change in value. Could anyone please let me know if I'm doing anything wrong?

Comment: After `substr` last symbol in your string is a space :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't this the same as:
Find the first space in a string. 
If the position > 20 take the first 20 characters. If the position < 20 take all characters up until the space.

```
declare
  l_position pls_integer;
  l_string varchar2(100) := 'Thisissomestringwith spaces';
begin
  l_position := least(instr(l_string,' ')-1,20);
  dbms_output.put_line(substr(l_string,1,l_position));
end;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
set serveroutput on;
    declare
    v_building_nam varchar2(100) :='lnkilap Mahallesi Üntel Sok. B1Blok';
    begin
    FOR I IN 1..10
    LOOP EXIT WHEN LENGTH(V_BUILDING_NAM) <=20;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(I);
    v_building_nam := substr(v_building_nam,1,instr(v_building_nam,' ',-1)-1); --calculate previous position of space
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(V_BUILDING_NAM);
    END LOOP;
   dbms_output.put_line(v_building_nam);
    END;
    /
```

you are taking space as your last position you should take less 1 position

Comment: I'd suggest saving the substr to a temp variable and checking if it's NULL, and only if it is not to set v_building_nam equal to it. This avoids the issue if there is not a space in the final 20 characters which would give a negative length for SUBSTR which causes it to return NULL.

Comment: Yes i accept that John that was is valid since instr will return 0 if no spaces found